# How display velocity variable in a CSS Class

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, velocity, liferay-theme

Please How can I display ***$num*** as a number in the console using velocity template.
I did:

```
 #foreach ($nav_item in $nav_items)

                 #set( $num = $velocityCount + 1 )

<li class="$nav_item megamenu-$num-columns-group $num" id="layout_$nav_item.getLayoutId()" $nav_item_attr_selected role="presentation">
```

but when I run it I didn't get the number in the class but it keeped $num.

Solution Please ?
 [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRUcC.png)

Comment: How about just `megamenu-$num-`

Comment: yes I tested it 
but still the same issues :(

Comment: You can also try `megamenu-${num}`

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks it is done now.

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Comment: as you told me :  megamenu-${num}

Comment: Should I post that as an answer?

Comment: Yes Sure ! 
It worked fine for me

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, the right way to implement this solution is just using `${theVar}`:

```
<li class="$nav_item megamenu-${num}-columns-group ${num}"
```